# Clicking qt .app vs running .exe in terminal

Tags: macos, qt, c++11, clang, ipc

I have a qt gui that spawns a c++11 clang server in osx 10.8 xcode

It does a cryptographic proof-of-work mining of a name (single mining thread)

when i click .app process takes 4 1/2 hours

when i run the exact exe inside the .app folder, from the terminal, process takes 30 minutes

question, how do i debug this?

thank you

====================================

even worse:

mining server running in terminal.

if i start GUI program that connect to server and just sends (ipc) it the "mine" command: 4 hours

if I start a CL-UI that connects to server and just sends (ipc) it the "mine" command: 30 minutes

both cases the server is mining in a tight loop. corrupt memory? single CPU is at 100%, as it should be..  cant figure it out.

========= 
this variable is is used w/o locking...

```
volatile bool running = true;
```

server thread

```
 fut = std::async(&Commissioner::generateName, &comish, name, m_priv.get_public_key() );
```

server loop...

```
nonce_t reset = std::numeric_limits<nonce_t>::max()-1000;
while ( running && hit < target ) {
    if ( nt.nonce >= reset   ) 
    {
        nt.utc_sec = fc::time_point::now();
        nt.nonce = 0;
    }
    else { ++nt.nonce; }

    hit = difficulty(nt.id());
}
```

Comment: Does your GUI eventually trigger a lot of status requests? Can you paste the connect/mine and eventual signal/slot/event code segements? If the server would run independently from the UI the results would be the same. You could check if your GUI Program's load is on the same core/cpu as your server.

Comment: how could i see the load? its probably a contex switch.. also maybe its the ipc library? there are heartbeats back and forth.

Comment: Do you manually request hte heartbeat messages? If so try to decrease the amount of requests. Another option may be to check the console log in osx if there are status logs

Comment: no - gui sends, then server replies.. anyways i already turned off teh heartbeats and still same thing.

Comment: so far the only thing i see different is "page ins" the slower process, has around 200 and the fast process has 0... still doesnt explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

evidence is now pointing to deterministic chaotic behavior. just very sensitive to initial conditions.

initial condition may be the timestamp data within the object that is hashed during mining.

mods please close.